# phpMyAdmin - "Import Successfully Finished" | "Error" - No tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

[image: Adminer Export Window]

[image: Successful Upload and then Error]

I am attempting to upload a copy of a WordPress website from a local environment to the web. I have exported the database from the local site using Adminer (see screenshot below of export parameters). However, when I upload the database to phpMyAdmin I get a strange message. It says that the upload was completed, but then there is an error message. It says that the "DROP DATABASE" statement is disabled. Incidentally, none of my tables are there.

Can I turn off the disablement of the DROP DATABASE statement? Would that help? What do I need to do?

Comment: Drop table, means it deletes the existing tables and create new ones.

Comment: Right. I want to make sure the current tables are dropped and the new ones added.